# Video background plugin in webpage that works with Android and iPhone(4 and up)?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, iphone, html5-video

I'm developing a webpage for mobile devices, I need a plugin (jQuery, JavaScript, any...) that works in iPhone (version 4 and up) and android (4.4 and up) but I can't find any, I have tried many, for example http://vodkabears.github.io/vide/ which I really like, but doesn't work on android, I have tried (using html 5) putting the video directly like this :

```
    <video id="videobackground" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop" muted="muted" volume="0">
       <source src="video/myvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
       <source src="video/myvideo.webm" type="video/webm">
      Sorry, your browser does not support HTML5 video.
   </video>
```

but again it does not work on android (cant test it on ios right now), btw, android using Chrome...

i cant seem to find a way to make it work on both devices...

I know that video as background is not optimal, I actually don't like it, but my client want it...

I don't care for device rotation, I just want to be able to autoplay the video as background (there will be only one button on top of the video)...

Also I need it to be muted, so no sound or what so ever...

TLDR: is there a way to put video as background in a webpage and be able to view it in IOS devices and ANDRIOD devices?